# run multiple npm script from another directories by writing only one command

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal, npm

I have application with frontend and backend folders. With structure like this.

```
application
├── frontend
│   └── src 
│   └── build
│   └── package.json
└── backend
    └── src
    └── build
    └── package.json
```

Frontend is default `create-react-app` application. Backend is in `nodejs` also with it's own `package.json` file.

Every time when I need to run application I run two command's.

```
npm start -> for frontend
```

and

```
npm run dev -> for backend
```

And I'm wondering is this possible to somehow combine this two commands as one bash command?

I don't have any bash experience so pls sorry if question is dummy.

OS: Macos

Comment: I could write a general answer, but I don't know `npm` at all, so there's a risk such answer would mislead you. You can help me help you. Please answer the following: (1) Are `-> for …` actual arguments or your *comments*? (2) Does `npm start …` need to be invoked in a specific directory? What directory? (3) Does `npm run dev …` need to be invoked in a specific directory? What directory? (4) Does `npm start …` exit by itself and you can run the other command in the same shell? Or do you need another shell because the first command runs in the foreground and you need it to keep running?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski 1) -> this is comments. 2) Yup, `/Users/projects/myproject/global/frontend` 3) `/Users/projects/myproject/global/backend` 4) No it does not exit itselt. I need to keep running  `npm start` and `npm run dev`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may perhaps be a more elegant way, but I just chain commands using `&&`, which conditionally runs the second command if the first is successful, or `;`, which doesn't care about the result of the previous command. See an SO thread on this [here](https://superuser.com/questions/442802/combining-commands-on-the-terminal-on-mac-os-x). This allows you to `cd` into the directory you want to operate in prior to running the command (see `secondScript` in my example below).

As a bonus (though not really related to your question), I also always install (`npm-run-all`)[https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all] in my projects and make heavy use of `run-s` and `run-p` (run sequentially or run in parallel) to combine my npm scripts. So you could start up your backend and then your front with a single command (that invokes two others).

Example (works on mac and linux, or Windows using WSL; on Windows, the command seperator is `;`):

In "scripts":

```
"firstScript": "run firstScript",
"secondScript": "cd ./submodule && run secondScript"
"bothScripts": "run-s firstScript secondScript"
"
```